# BlenRig Mouth Control Issue

Tags: rigging

Not sure if anyone around he re knows but I have tried to use BlenRig to rig a character I made. Everything works except certain controls from the `mouth_ctrl` control bone.

I can move it side to side and the mouth moves correctly but when I move it up and down the mouth does not open like it is supposed to. The Vincent Character that is rigged using BlenRig works fine. Is there a control or setting I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior might be caused by having the property JAW_ROTATION of the mouth_ctrl bone set to zero. Setting it to it to 60 should solve your problem.

[image]

You can find it in the CUSTOM PROPERTIES panel at the Blenrig 5 tab (like in the image above), the Properties panel at the Properties shelf or the Custom Properties panel at the Bone tab in the Properties window.